# getting error - Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple in Spring boot JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Trying to access selected columns by renaming with alias with native query. for the same, i have implemented interface to collection them. But, getting `Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple`

**Code**

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>
    {
        @Query(value="SELECT t.id as user_id,t.name as user_name from {h-schema}user t WHERE t.pincode=:pincode", nativeQuery = true)
        public Set<UserList> dataTrainerGuides(@Param("pincode") String pincode);
        public static interface UserList 
        {
            String getUser_id();
            String getUser_name();
        }
    }
```

Comment: which Spring Data and Hibernate versions are you using?

Comment: @galovics Springboot version: 1.5.8.RELEASE and Springboot JPA : 2.1

Comment: This is possibly this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1209 Please check